# Regex. Число состоит из 1 до 6 ти цифр, и чиcло не должно быть равно нулю

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Regex. Число состоит из 1 до 6 ти цифр, и чило не должно быть равно нулю.

Есть число которое может быть однозначным - шестизначным, включать цифры от 0 до 9

1. 1 это число 1
2. 02 это число 2
3. 456 это число 456
4. 9999 это число 9999
5. 00001 это число 1
6. 700708

но число не должно быть равно нулю

1. 0
2. 00
3. 000
4. 0000
5. 00000
6. 000000

я решила это так, работает, но не красиво написано

([1-9]|([0]{1,5}[1-9])|([0]{1,4}[1-9][0-9])|([0]{1,3}[1-9][0-9]{1,2})|([0]{1,2}[1-9][0-9]{1,3})|([0][1-9][0-9]{1,4})|([1-9][0-9]{1,5}))

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Comment: Дайте нормальные примеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Число из от 1 до 6 цифр и не ноль:
    ^(?!0+$)\d{1,6}$

Comment: очень благодарна за ваш ответ!)

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте совет что почитать, не очень понятно как именно это работает (?!0+$), хочу разобраться

Comment: По поводу литературы не подскажу, а вот объяснить постараюсь: ?! - отрицательное утверждение (противоположность ?=), 0+$ - один или больше нулей вплоть до конца текста. В итоге данное выражение в результат не попадает, но является доп условием регялярки. Т.е. это как буд-то логическое и - конъюнкция.

Comment: огромное спасибо))))